# Keyboard shortcut has wrong description for undeleting a post

Tags: bug, deleted-posts, keyboard-shortcuts, vote-to-undelete

It's possible to delete/undelete a post with the keyboard shortcut <kbd>M</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>. After pressing <kbd>M</kbd> on a deleted post, the menu says <kbd>D</kbd> is for 'delete', but it should say 'undelete' in this case.

[image: Keyboard shortcut menu shown next to a deleted post. The description for the "D" shortcut says "delete"]